# What is the traditional way to layer a lasagna?

Tags: pasta, italian-cuisine, lasagna

I am following this [recpie](https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2016/12/lasagna-bolognese-al-forno-recipe.html) to make a lasagna (minus the ragu because jewish law) and I always wonder how to best layer the lasagna.

Below is a picture of how I layer my lasagna. Is this the correct way in terms of white/red sauce ratio, cheese and seasoning? Is it ok that the sheets don't cover the entire casserole?
[image]

Comment: Isn't the ratio of red and white sauce and cheese etc a complete matter of taste?

Comment: @Johannes_B I am interested in the traditional way. And the ratio is just one part of the question - I wonder if the pasta leaves are layered in a good way. Or if im overloading the leaves with sauce.

Comment: If you are interested in 'the traditional way' an option is to Google [lasagna tradizionale site:.it](https://www.google.com/search?q=lasagna+tradizionale+site%3A.it). You will find plenty of videos so any language barrier is irrelevant

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Traditionally, you start with a layer of pasta at the bottom, then go ragu-bechamel-lasagne-ragu-bechamel-lasagne, and finish with a layer of bechamel directly on top of the last pasta layer, followed by a liberal covering of grated parmesan.

It is also common to add a sprinkling of parmesan on top of the bechamel in each layer.

Ratios are subjective but I would say it is normal to have roughly twice as much ragu as bechamel

Answer (score 4):

There are probably as many variations as there are people making it.  It's probably a good idea to spread the ragu/red sauce a bit more evenly (I usually use a vegetarian ragu with lentils instead of the meat)

I tend to make mine ragu/pasta/bechamel/pasta/ragu/pasta/bechamel/cheese but regard that as a matter of preference. I think this approach is common in France, which almost certainly means it's not authentically Italian. Actually, there's some cheese added to the bechamel in my version.  I also use the type of lasagne that doesn't need precooking, which absorbs a bit more water from the sauces and thickens everything

I find it better to have the pasta slightly underfill the dish than end up trying to tessellate fiddly bits.

But this is all a matter of preference.